# sumproduct - sum the number and ignore text

Tags: excel, formula, sumproduct

I used SUMPRODUCT formula to retrieve value from column C2:E4 which contains a number and a text value, but I want to ignore the text

Example of my desired result:

```
A    B       C     D    E    F     G     H

NO.  NAME    YES   NO   YES        YES   80  
1.   Dave    10    20    x
2.   Sue      x    10   30
3.   Hans    10     y   30
```

In H2, this formula works when there is no Text cells:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$1:$E$1=G1)*($C$2:$E$4))
```

In this code I have tried to use **ISNUMBER** to ignore text *(x and y)*, but it doesn't work.
I have already tried several ways to make it work but it doesn't.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pertaining to the use of `SUMPRODUCT` and `ISNUMBER` formulae, this is what i got after testing.

`=SUMPRODUCT(($C$1:$E$1=G1)*--ISNUMBER($C$2:$E$4),($C$2:$E$4))`

the double negative helps to ignore the text values (x and y), while adding an additional array helps to compute the sum correctly (without the array, the output gives `4`).

hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=SUM(C:C)*(C1=G1)+SUM(D:D)*(D1=G1)+SUM(E:E)*(E1=G1)
```

Comment: is this not excessive? I mean, if the reference is from C2 to Y80. That is too tiring

Comment: @PulungUdaraManggiling you asked for someone to make it work, don’t complain it is too long...

Comment: @solar mike, I just ask. sorry for making you upset, brother.

Comment: If the solution works for you, then you should accept it or at least upvote it...